# Swift 4: How to post a file in params with Alamofire?

Tags: file, upload, swift4, alamofire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FklLe.png)

The image is Postman example of how I uploaded file to backend API. I am struggling on how to upload the file or image.png/jpg using Alamofire? Because I can't include the file in Param.

Comment: with the help of multipart, you can send file/image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let image = UIImage.init(named: "myImage")
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!

let parameters = ["custid": 1] //Optional for extra parameter

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            } //Optional for extra parameters
    },
to:"mysite/upload.php")
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
             print(response.result.value)  
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)  
    }
}
```